# How to cancel or restart Task inherits List and await?

Tags: c#, async-await

I use a async method to call an api to get a list of entries and fill a listbox with this data. This async method i want to call every 120 seconds. At this point it is necessary to cancel or restart the task to prevent memory leak right?
I have no idea how to cancel or restart my task. Do you have any idea to figure this out?
Here my Method:

```
public async Task GetChatters()
    {
        List<TwitchLib.Api.Core.Models.Undocumented.Chatters.ChatterFormatted> chatters = await api.Undocumented.GetChattersAsync(channelName);

        foreach (var chatter in chatters)
        {
            ListBoxViewerUpdate(chatter.Username);
        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(viewerListUpdateTime));
        Task.Factory.StartNew(GetChatters);
    }
```

thank you =)

Comment: " ... right?" Well, no? First of all, if you're creating methods that are async, you really should consider passing a `CancellationToken` to it if you want it to be cancellable. Then, to cancel it, you would call the `Cancel()` method on the `CancellationTokenSource` that provided that token. Inside your method, you would ideally check `IsCancellationRequested`  or call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` periodically on the token. But you don't **have** to do any of this to prevent a memory leak. Why do you think so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cancel "the task" because your API is not cancellable.

A task, by itself, will not cause that much memory leakage. But your recursive algorithm will cause memory leakeage because it will keep those tasks and the state machine generated by the compiler alive.

You should also use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `async-await`.